# To convert Unichar Array into a single NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I created an unicode char array using 'characterAtIndex:' from an NSString object.

I want to make the characters in the array again into a single complete string.

Is there any method to convert this unicahr Array into NSStirng?
Can anyone please help me???

This s my code:

```
NSString *sentence = @"A long string";
NSString *new = [[NSString alloc]init];
unichar aBuffer[[sent length]];
int j=0;
//Tried to reverse the string:
for (int i=[sent length]-1; i>=0; i--,j++) {
    aBuffer[j]=[sent characterAtIndex:i];
    }
```

I found a better way for sting reversal than this, but let me know whether we have any method for this...

Comment: Post your code where you are creating char array

Comment: 1. Do not name variables `new`, it is a keyword in C++. 2. There is no reason to ever call `[[NSString alloc] init]` other than to leak memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the array a standard c array? (looks something like this: `array[50];`) If it is, you can do this:

```
[NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar*) length:(NSUInteger)];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert to a `unichar` and back using `getCharacters:range:` and `stringWithCharacters:`.

```
NSString *sentence = @"A long unicode sentence";

NSUInteger length = [sentence length];
unichar aBuffer[length + 1];

[sentence getCharacters:aBuffer range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];
aBuffer[length] = 0x0;

NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithCharacters:aBuffer length:length];

NSLog(@"%@", newStr);
```

Comment: @ramgandhi I updated the code to use an array and removed the need for you to use a loop to fill the array.

Answer (score 2):

Get a `NSString` from a bytes array with:

```
- (id)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

(and you could use `UTF8String` instead of looping through the string with `characterAtIndex:`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toll-Free Bridging to turn a char array into an objective-c class  or reverse.

You can create a `CFMutableStringRef` variable with your array  lets say the variable is myString. Than you can create a string or a mutable string with it.

```
NSMutableString* objcString = (NSMutableString*) myString;
```